# jQuery Check whether has class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

I have class "booked" and "available" in .css
I use in jQuery(for add class on element)

I have data in array and used in ajax.

this is a sample how I add or remove class :

```
 $.ajax({
    url: "URL.aspx/GetData",
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

    success: function (response) {            
        var arr = JSON.parse(response.d);           
        objData = new Array();
        objData = arr;
        for (i = 0; i < objData.length; i++) {                
            jQuery('#' + objData[i].noSeat).addClass('seat-availiable');
            jQuery('#class-' + objData[i].noSeat).attr('value', 'seat-availiable');
            jQuery('#' + objData[i].noSeat).removeClass('seat-booked');
```

But my question is "How can I check if element has class booked or available class ? "

Comment: [How do I test whether an element has a particular class?](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-test-whether-an-element-has-a-particular-class/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `hasClass` method will work: http://api.jquery.com/hasclass/

```
$('#mydiv').hasClass('booked') || $('#mydiv').hasClass('available')
```

Comment: Holy jQuery, wow. But the real question is, does it have basic arithmetic?

Comment: Why not? `jQuery.globalEval("var x = 3+3;alert(x);")` :)

Comment: Not enough jQuery. I require an `add()`, `subtract()`, `multiply()`, etc. function (but no divide; dividing is for hipsters who can't multiply by the reciprocal). Maybe there's a jQuery plugin for that.

Comment: i didn't use clas in div. i use like this 
jQuery("#1-8").addClass("seat-availiable");
            jQuery("#class-1-8").attr("value", "seat-availiable");

Comment: how i use it ? @JasonW

Comment: Just replace your `addClass` with `hasClass`, so `jQuery("#1-8").hasClass("seat-availiable")` will return true if the class is on the element, false otherwise

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="specificDiv">

 $("#specificDiv").hasClass("active")
```

Above return true if `#specificDiv`  id as `.active` class else it will return `false`